# Get session value from hyperlink and pass it to another page in JSP

Tags: session

I have a page which shows a table from backend in the frontend using the  tag.
Now i have used a while loop to display the no. of rows of the table. In the table there are 3 columns namely "NAME","DATE","CREATED BY". Now i have put the "NAME" column within a  tag to make it a link, so that when the user click a particular name i want that name value to go to another page which i have mentioned within the href="" property of the  tag. I am trying to use session variable to use it, but null value is only getting passed. Here is my code :

```
<%
    try
    {
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:xyz","sa","pass");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from Topic where Status='Approved'");


       %><table border="1"  style="table-layout: fixed; width: 500px"  >
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Created By</th>

                </tr>
                <%

while(rs.next()){%>

                <tr align="center">

                    <td height="20px"><a href="topiccomment.jsp"><%=rs.getString("TName")%></a></td>
                    <td height="20px"><%=rs.getString("Date")%></td>
                    <td height="20px"><%=rs.getString("Username")%></td>

                </tr>


             <%}%></table><br/><%

}
catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

%>
```

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/9bq2akjq7/Screen_Hunter_16_Apr_15_22_37.jpg

Comment: When i click "MY Topic 1" it should go to "topiccomment.jsp" which should have the value "My Topic 1" in a String variable. If i choose "tamal's topic" it should sent that value, like this